# Malloc changing values in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I am having an issue with my malloc call. I have the following code:

```
int** parseEntireFile(int *sizeArray)
{
FILE * fp;
char buffer[5000];
int size = 0;
int a,b,c;
int res;
int **someArray;

fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp)!= NULL)
{
    size++;
}

fclose(fp);

fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
someArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
size = 0;

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
    res = sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (res == 3)
    {
        someArray[size] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 500);
        someArray[size][0] = a;
        someArray[size][1] = b;
        someArray[size][2] = c;


    }else if (res == 2) {
        someArray[size] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 500);
        someArray[size][0] = a;
        someArray[size][1] = b;
        someArray[size][2] = 0;

    } else if (res == 1) {
        printf ("1 value %d\n", a);
    } else
    {
        printf ("0 values\n");
    }
    size++;

}

*sizeArray = size;
return someArray;
}
```

All this works fine, but in my main I declare an array of struct pointers and malloc it:

```
struct allData **certainData;
certainData = malloc(sizeof(struct allData) * size);
```

When I add this code into my program the rest of the program is printing wrong values, but when I take the malloc out its fine. Does anybody know where the issue could be?

Comment: `someArray` is an array of `int *`, pointers to int. Therefore, you should allocate `size * sizeof(int *)`; `size *  sizeof(int)` may be too small. Conversely, your allocations to `someArray[i]` shiould be based on `sizeof(int)`. (A good pattern is to do something like `p = malloc(n * sizeof(*p))`, where the correct type is derived from what `p` points to.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 someArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

should be

```
 someArray = malloc(sizeof(int*) * size);
```

probably your platform has sizeof(int*) != sizeof(int).

Comment: And under that it should be `sizeof(int)` again ;)

Comment: @Joshua I just tested both, it isn't either that is causing the problem. It's below where I malloc the struct it is causing my program to print values it shouldnt be

Comment: There is no place where you malloc a struct.

Answer (score -1):

`someArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);`
should not compile. malloc is supposed to return `void*`, so you should cast it.

Also, like the comment says, it should be allocating an array of pointers.

If pointers are larger than ints, like in a typical 64 bit build, you'd be overrunning `someArray` and writing on whatever else you have in the stack. So you should expect wrong values, `certainData` being smashed etc.

Comment: The question is about C, where implicit conversion from `void *` is legal. The cast in only necessary in C++.

Comment: "*so you should cast it.*" No, as in C it's not needed nor recommended to cast `void*`.